Ratelimit or prevent exessive rpc calls on database functions on Supabase
I'm still very new to working with databases so I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
I am working on a webapp game where votes can be cast on player submissions.
I created a vote function that takes a uuid of a post from the client and the function awards a vote to the selected post. A player informed me of how this could be abused by creating a loop that continuously casts votes on a targeted post using the uuid.
An idea I have is using a backend environment variable for validation so requests can only come from the webapp though I'm not certain if this would actually prevent abuse.
Any helpful advice or resources to help me with this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

If you want to have only one person be able to vote per submission, you an create a votes table with user_id and submission_id foreign keys. Then you can add a unique constraint on those two columns so that a single user can only vote once per submission.
